# How configure Azure Application Gateway to allow connecting to a Container Instance

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-container-instances

I have a private network (`10.0.0.0/16`) which has multiple subnets. I have an Application Gateway configured in the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet and I would like to expose Container Instances from the `10.0.2.0/24` subnet to the internet via HTTP.

The gateway has only one HTTP rule simply mapping 80:80 from the internet to the backend pool. In the "Backend Health" section the status of my container (added via IP address) is unknown and the following error is displayed:

> Unable to retrieve health status data. Check presence of NSG/UDR blocking access to ports 65503-65534 from Internet to Application Gateway.

Initially I had no NSG set but after setting one (and even allowing any:any) is not solving the status check problem.

When opening the url in the browser I get an 502 Bad Gateway error.

Note: I have added a container isntance which is not part of the VNet to the Application Gateway and despite also showing unknonw status in the Backend Pool the requests actually got redirected to the container, so I am almost certain I am misconfiguring someting in the VNet.

Note2: I have pushed a test container and the test container can reach the container I am trying to expose in the same subnet, so something goes wrong between the container and the application gateway.

My questions is what NSG rules I have to set to

1. make the container visible to the health check
2. make the redirect work between the Application Gateway and the Container

Comment: What does your app show when you call the health probe directly? You might have to provision a VM on this Vnet in order to do this. The inline shell is good to simply launch a shell command in order to get this. Keep in mind that the backend status shows health status of all listeners.

Comment: > What does your app show when you call the health probe directly?

Do you mean the URL? When I call it for from an another container on the same network then it returns 200 OK. 

> Keep in mind that the backend status shows health status of all listeners

I believe it shows the status for every added host/IP in the backend pool individually.

Comment: Just to be sure: is the app gateway and containers on the same subnet or not? If not, can you try to reach the probe from the app gateway subnet?

Comment: No they are not, but it's impossible for them to be deployed into the same subnet, because to deploy containers you need to delegate the given subnet to container instances (aka only containers can be deployed into int and nothing else. However the subnets can see each other, because I have added an any:any rule for data coming from the virtual network and going into the same virtual network. Anyway I will create new subnet and deploy the test container into that just to make sure subnets can see each other.

Answer (score 0):

there is really nothing to misconfigure, you can create a vm in one of the subnets (create a third one) and test if it can access the container instance? if it can 0 this might be a platform limitation, tbh.

But looking at the error: you should detach all NSG\User Defined routes from the Vnet (for simplicity) and do several other checks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#backend-health-status-unknown